# Apache .htaccess RewriteCond to allow special URL (write it in one string)

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I need some help with writing RewriteCond in 1 string correctly for:

`www.mydomain.com/?q=home` (both https and http)

**Important:**

```
www.mydomain.com/administration/?q=home
```

etc and

```
www.mydomain.com/?q=home&z=123
```

etc should NOT be proccessed. Only

```
www.mydomain.com/?q=home
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site. 
This will work for http/s

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#if the request only has q=home
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /\?q=home\  [NC]  
# then add Rewrite rule here
```

Comment: Just one question, please, if you don't mind... Could you please explain the meaning of "^[A-Z]{3,9}\" ? I've tried to find it out, but Google skips such queries. Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec The `^[A-Z]{3,9}\` will match any HTTP Verb i.e. `GET`, `POST`, `DELETE` etc. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods

Answer (score 3):

The below 2 rewriteconds, should process only for `www.mydomain.com/?q=whateverstring`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=([^&]+)$ [NC]
```

add whatever `RewriteRule` you want after the above.